# how to create a neumorphic circular graph in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface, figma

I have been working on a flutter project which requires me to create neumorphic graph as shown in the design. I created the design in figma but I am having trouble replicating the design in flutter. I used 'percentage indicator' package to create the graph but i dont know how to give it a neumorphic look.[Figma design. The progress bar is the element which is causing me trouble](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DD7TF.png)

This is the code which i tried

```
CircularPercentIndicator(
                      radius: 67.5,
                      lineWidth: 0.2632 * 67.5,
                      percent: 0.65,
                      progressColor: Colors.green,
                      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                      circularStrokeCap: CircularStrokeCap.round,
                      reverse: true,
                    ),
```

And this is the result
[replicated part from emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a6mOQ.png)